# xsl 1.0 Group by with comma separated items

Tags: xslt, group-by

I have a XML similar to this

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <customer>customer a </customer>
  <collateral>
    <summary>summary a</summary>
   <related>
     <solutions>sol1,sol2</solutions>
   </related>
  <collateral>
</profile>
<profile>
  <customer>customer b </customer>
  <collateral>
    <summary>summary b</summary>
   <related>
     <solutions>sol1</solutions>
   </related>
  <collateral>
</profile>

<profile>
  <customer>customer c </customer>
  <collateral>
    <summary>summary c</summary>
   <related>
     <solutions>sol2,sol3</solutions>
   </related>
  <collateral>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Desired output

```
<div id="#sol1">
  customer a,summary a
 customer b, summary b
</div>

<div id="#sol2">
  customer a,summary a
  customer c,summary c
</div>
```

..............

Iam aware of Muenchian way of grouping, but not sure how I can accomplish, if I have comma separated groub-by element values. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**While this is straight-forward in XSLT 2.0, in XSLT a two-pass transformation can produce the wanted results**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSolByVal" match="solution" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)
                /*/*/*/*
                   /solutions/solution
                    [generate-id()
                    =
                    generate-id(key('kSolByVal', .)[1])
                    ]"
   mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="pass2" match="solution">
  <div id="#{.}">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
       select="key('kSolByVal', .)/../../../.."/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="profile" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat(customer, ', ', */summary, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="solutions">
   <solutions>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="split"/>
   </solutions>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="solutions" name="split" mode="split">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

   <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
    <xsl:variable name="vText1"
         select="concat($pText, ',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vPart" select=
       "substring-before($vText1, ',')"/>

     <solution>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vPart"/>
     </solution>

     <xsl:call-template name="split">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText"
           select="substring($pText, string-length($vPart)+2)"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected for well-formedness):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <customer>customer a </customer>
        <collateral>
            <summary>summary a</summary>
            <related>
                <solutions>sol1,sol2</solutions>
            </related>
        </collateral>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <customer>customer b </customer>
        <collateral>
            <summary>summary b</summary>
            <related>
                <solutions>sol1</solutions>
            </related>
        </collateral>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <customer>customer c </customer>
        <collateral>
            <summary>summary c</summary>
            <related>
                <solutions>sol2,sol3</solutions>
            </related>
        </collateral>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div id="#sol1">
customer a , summary a
customer b , summary b
</div>
<div id="#sol2">
customer a , summary a
customer c , summary c
</div>
<div id="#sol3">
customer c , summary c
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

1. We carry out the transformation in two passes. Pass2 is applied on the result of applying Pass1 on the provided XML document.
2. Pass 1 is essentially the identity rule overriden for any `solutions` element. The processing of a `solutions` element consists in recursive splitting of its string value. The final result of Pass1 is the following:

--

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <customer>customer a </customer>
      <collateral>
         <summary>summary a</summary>
         <related>
            <solutions>
               <solution>sol1</solution>
               <solution>sol2</solution>
            </solutions>
         </related>
      </collateral>
   </profile>
   <profile>
      <customer>customer b </customer>
      <collateral>
         <summary>summary b</summary>
         <related>
            <solutions>
               <solution>sol1</solution>
            </solutions>
         </related>
      </collateral>
   </profile>
   <profile>
      <customer>customer c </customer>
      <collateral>
         <summary>summary c</summary>
         <related>
            <solutions>
               <solution>sol2</solution>
               <solution>sol3</solution>
            </solutions>
         </related>
      </collateral>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

.3. We then apply templates (in `mode="pass2"`) on the result of Pass1. This is a typical and traditional Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Also, for the explanation of the solution. If you don't mind. Why is that we need to assign this to a variable  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
And also the need for ext:node-set? Thanks again

Comment: @gechu: This is necessary in XSLT 1.0. The result of the transformation that is captured in a variable is of the infamous RTF (Resut Tree Fragment) type and it cannot be accessed further by XPath expressions that regard it as anything not string. Here comes the extension function xxx:node-set() that is provided by any XSLT vendor (and is different for different vendors). This function takes an RTF and converts it to a "regular" tree -- one that can be manipulated as a tree.

Comment: Not sure if I can ask a additional question here. In the output if I want to show it like this how will I do it.<div id="#sol3">
customer a , summary a
customer b , summary b
</div>
<div id="#sol1">
customer a , summary a
customer c , summary c
</div>
<div id="#sol2">
customer c , summary c
</div>

Comment: a mistake in the previous update. THe output should be like .<div id="#sol3"> customer c , summary c </div> <div id="#sol1"> customer a , summary a customer b , summary b</div> <div id="#sol2"> customer a , summary a customer c , summary c </div>

Comment: @gechu: Please, ask a new question for this.